# AHK: convert text selection to hyperlink with clipboard as target

Tags: vba, ms-word, autohotkey, word-interop

Using Autohotkey to achieve this behaviour:

- copy URL from browser
- select text in word doc
- press keyboard shortcut
- AHK converts selected text to hyperlink with clipboard as target.

This is what I have so far:

```
^b::
wd := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
url := %clipboard%
wd.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(wd.Selection.Range, %url%,"","","")
return
```

I've tried many other variations, but alway get the error that the url variable contains illegal characters.

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs.

```
^b::
    wd := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
    url := clipboard
    wd.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(wd.Selection.Range, url,"","","")
return
```

or

```
^b::
    wd := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
    wd.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(wd.Selection.Range, clipboard,"","","")
return
```